# How to train the ResNet50?

Tags: keras, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0

[Creating Deeper Bottleneck ResNet from Scratch using Tensorflow](https://towardsdatascience.com/creating-deeper-bottleneck-resnet-from-scratch-using-tensorflow-93e11ff7eb02)
Hi everyone, recently I've been learning how to create ResNet50 using tf.keras according to the link given above. My question is, to train this machine, should I assign the 'input' variable (line 75) with the dataset I wished to train with? If so, how should I do that?

```
#import the needed libraries

from tensorflow.python.keras.utils.vis_utils import model_to_dot
from IPython.display import SVG
import pydot
import graphviz


from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.layers import MaxPool2D, GlobalAvgPool2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Add, ReLU, Dense
from tensorflow.keras import Model

'''import tensorflow
print(tensorflow.__version__)'''

#Conv-BatchNorm-ReLU block

def conv_batchnorm_relu(x, filters, kernel_size, strides=1):

  x = Conv2D(filters=filters, kernel_size=kernel_size, strides=strides, padding = 'same')(x)
  x = BatchNormalization()(x)
  x = ReLU()(x)

  return x

#identity block

def identity_block(tensor, filters):
  x = conv_batchnorm_relu(tensor, filters = filters, kernel_size = 1, strides = 1)
  x = conv_batchnorm_relu(x, filters = filters, kernel_size = 3, strides = 1)
  x = Conv2D(filters = 4 * filters, kernel_size = 1, strides = 1)(x)
  x = BatchNormalization()(x)

  x = Add()([tensor, x])  #skip connection
  x = ReLU()(x)

  return x

#Projection block

def projection_block(tensor, filters, strides):

  #left stream
  x = conv_batchnorm_relu(tensor, filters = filters, kernel_size = 1, strides = strides)
  x = conv_batchnorm_relu(x, filters = filters, kernel_size = 3, strides = 1)
  x = Conv2D(filters = 4 * filters, kernel_size = 1, strides = 1)(x)
  x = BatchNormalization()(x)

  #right stream
  shortcut = Conv2D(filters = 4 * filters, kernel_size = 1, strides = strides)(tensor)
  shortcut = BatchNormalization()(shortcut)

  x = Add()([shortcut, x])        #skip connection
  x = ReLU()(x)

  return x

#Resnet Block
#First block is always projection. While others are identity blocks

def resnet_block(x, filters, reps, strides):

  x = projection_block(x, filters, strides)
  for i in range(reps-1):
    x = identity_block(x, filters)

  return x



#Create Model

input = Input(shape = (244,244,3))      #Should I assign this input variable with dataset? If so, how do I do that?

#################
x = conv_batchnorm_relu(input, filters = 64, kernel_size = 7, strides = 2)
x = MaxPool2D(pool_size = 3, strides = 2)(x)
x = resnet_block(x, filters = 64, reps = 3, strides = 1)
x = resnet_block(x, filters=128, reps =4, strides=2)
x = resnet_block(x, filters=256, reps =6, strides=2)
x = resnet_block(x, filters=512, reps =3, strides=2)
x = GlobalAvgPool2D()(x)

#################
output = Dense(1000, activation = 'softmax')(x)

model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=output)
model.summary()

SVG(model_to_dot(model, show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True, rankdir='TB',expand_nested=False, 
dpi=60, subgraph=False).create(prog='dot',format='svg'))
```

Comment: No, you just cal model.fit with the appropriate parameters.

Comment: Look up how to train a Keras model (any will do, as you already know how to build the model you want). You'll have to compile the model with the loss and optimizer you want to use and then fit it with your data.